# Dependencies issues after dist-upgrade on raspberrypi

Tags: update

i updated my raspberry pi to the latest OS. During the upgrade process I had several issues especially one with user rights see:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474748/all-users-locked-login-not-possible

But now I can't update the system at all. I always getting the following error:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf : Depends: libctf-nobfd0 (>= 2.36) but it is not installed
                                Depends: libctf0 (>= 2.36) but it is not installed
                                Depends: libjansson4 (>= 2.14) but it is not installed
 g++ : Depends: cpp (= 4:12.2.0-3) but 4:8.3.0-1+rpi2 is installed
       Depends: g++-12 (>= 12.2.0-1~) but it is not installed
       Depends: gcc-12 (>= 12.2.0-1~) but it is not installed
 gcc : Depends: cpp (= 4:12.2.0-3) but 4:8.3.0-1+rpi2 is installed
       Depends: gcc-12 (>= 12.2.0-1~) but it is not installed
 libapt-pkg6.0 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9) but 8.3.0-6+rpi1 is installed
                 Recommends: apt (>= 2.0.9) but 1.8.2.3 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.29) but 2.36-9 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.28-10+rpt2+rpi1+deb10u2) but 2.36-9 is installed
 libstdc++-8-dev : Depends: libgcc-8-dev (= 8.3.0-6+rpi1) but it is not installable
 locales : Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.36) but 2.28-10+rpt2+rpi1+deb10u2 is installed
 python3 : Depends: python3.11 (>= 3.11.2-1~) but it is not installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.11.2-1+b1) but 3.7.3-1 is installed
 python3-apt : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but 8.3.0-6+rpi1 is installed
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.11.2-1+b1) but 3.7.3-1 is installed
               Depends: python3.11-dev (>= 3.11.2-1~) but it is not installed
               Depends: libjs-sphinxdoc (>= 5.2) but 1.8.4-1 is installed
 python3-yaml : Depends: libyaml-0-2 (>= 0.2.2~) but 0.2.1-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What did I tried already?

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt --fix-broken install
apt-get dist-upgrade
dpkg --configure -a
apt --install -f
apt -update --fix-missing
```

What a change made was:

```
apt  --fix-broken install -y -f
```

but still end with errors:

```
Checking init scripts...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam0g:armhf.postinst: 97: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam0g:armhf.postinst: awk: not found
dpkg: error processing package libpam0g:armhf (--configure):
 installed libpam0g:armhf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam0g:armhf
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

P.S: All tasks were executed as root

**Update 07/17/2023 11:04am:**
I think that this is the root cause why ithe apt command is not working:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam0g:armhf.postinst: 97: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam0g:armhf.postinst: awk: not found
```

This is whown when I try to run awk:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# awk
bash: /usr/bin/awk: No such file or directory
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d#
```

But mawk and awk are listes as you could see:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# ls -lisa /usr/bin/*awk
10669  0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    21 Feb 13  2020 /usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk
11823 96 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 94500 Apr  8  2012 /usr/bin/mawk
10763  0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    22 Feb 13  2020 /usr/bin/nawk -> /etc/alternatives/nawk
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d#
```

**Update 2023/07/18:
Output as requested by goldilocks:**

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/homebridge# stat $(readlink $(which awk))
  File: /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/mawk
  Size: 13              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: b302h/45826d    Inode: 131         Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-02-13 17:09:32.717677363 +0100
Modify: 2020-02-13 16:51:08.781282703 +0100
Change: 2020-02-13 17:09:32.717677363 +0100
 Birth: -
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/homebridge# ldd /usr/bin/mawk 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7effb000)
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so (0x76f80000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76f3f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76e28000)
        ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x76e09000)
        /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76fa0000)
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/homebridge#
```

Comment: "i updated my raspberry pi to the latest OS" What exactly did you do? Why did you ask on a Ubuntu site - are you running Ubuntu? DO NOT use `apt-get` in interactive mode - you may miss vital prompts - use `apt`

Comment: I changed the repos
`/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`
to bookworm, did an `apt dist-upgrade` and now I can't perform any updates anymore.

Comment: If you attempted this unsupported upgrade your OS is dead. The ONLY supported method for Raspberry Pi OS is a FRESH INSTALL but there is no Bullseye yet. If you did it on Ubuntu it is still dead - there has never been a  dist-upgrade which works on a Pi.

Comment: @Milliways I did dist-upgrades on my other pi's a while ago without any issues. But anyhow, the question is not if it is allowed or possible or not, the question is if there is a possibility to fix the error above which should be possible since I'm able to logon to the system.

Comment: Edit in the output from `stat $(readlink $(which awk))` and `ldd /usr/bin/mawk`.

Comment: @Milliways "there is no Bullseye yet" - of course, you mean there's no Bookworm yet - why Debian decided to name three releases in a row starting with B can get confusing :p

Comment: *if there is a possibility to fix the error* - perhaps restore the backup before you began and start over, documenting each step, because we don't know exactly what you did to get to the state you are currently in

Comment: @JaromandaX They should pick a different starting letter for each release (as novelists are recommended for each character).

Comment: @goldilocks: I've updated the Question

Comment: @JaromandaX: I can explain exactly what I did. I changed the repos to bookwor, did the upgrade and the system didn't upgraded successfully. I ended in a system where logon was impossible. Therfore I did the task mentionewd in the description of my problem. And now I'm at the stage of my problem ;)

Comment: That is weird, I'd love to know why -- but OTOH, this may just be a waste of time at this point.  Save your current install if you need it for any of the content (or save that content) and do a fresh install.

Comment: *did the upgrade* - ahh yes... see,when upgrading all my bullseye to bookworm (not pi's) the "did the upgrade" is not a single step, rather it is multiple steps. I was merely wondering what you actually did in those steps other than "did the upgrade" - which, of course, you didn't since you yourself say you failed\